# Extract values from a text file in linux

Tags: linux

I have a log file generated from sqlldr log file and I was wondering if I can write a shell to extract the following values from the log below using Linux. Thanks

Table_name:  TEST
Row_load:  100
Row_fail: 10
Date_run: Feb 07, 2014

```
Table TEST:
100 Rows successfully loaded.
10 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.

Bind array size not used in direct path.
Column array  rows :    5000
Stream buffer bytes:  256000
Read   buffer bytes: 1048576

Total logical records skipped:          0
Total logical records read:         14486
Total logical records rejected:         0
Total logical records discarded:        0
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader main thread:        3
Total stream buffers loaded by SQL*Loader load thread:        0

Run began on Fri Feb 07 12:21:24 2014
Run ended on Fri Feb 07 12:21:31 2014

Elapsed time was:     00:00:06.88
CPU time was:         00:00:00.11
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of your log file is always same, then you can do the following with `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==1 { sub(/:/,x); print "Table_name: "$NF}
NR==2 { print "Row_load: " $1}
NR==3 { print "Row_fail: " $1}
/Run ended/ { print "Date_run: "$5 FS $6","$8}' file
```

Output

```
$ awk '
NR==1 { sub(/:/,x); print "Table_name: "$NF}
NR==2 { print "Row_load: " $1}
NR==3 { print "Row_fail: " $1}
/Run ended/ { print "Date_run: "$5 FS $6","$8}' file
Table_name: TEST
Row_load: 100
Row_fail: 10
Date_run: Feb 07,2014
```